# How to create an inverted Toggle in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, state, toggle

I'm trying to create a view that has two toggles that both operate off the same variable, but the twist is that I want one to be the inverse of the variable and only be toggled on when the variable is false.

At first I looked for a simple way to invert the isOn variable with a well placed exclamation point:

```
> Toggle(isOn: $myStruct.myBooleanVar) {
                            Text("Yes").frame(width: 80)
                        }.toggleStyle(.button)
                        Toggle(isOn: $myStruct.!myBooleanVar) {
                            Text("no").frame(width: 80)
                        }.toggleStyle(.button)
```

I was unsuccessful

> '.!' is not a binary operator

Next I looked to see if there was a modifier I could put on the toggle to invert it. Something like:

```
> Toggle(isOn: $myStruct.myBooleanVar) {
                            Text("Yes").frame(width: 80)
                        }.toggleStyle(.button)
                        Toggle(isOn: $myStruct.myBooleanVar) {
                            Text("no").frame(width: 80)
                        }.toggleStyle(.button)
                        .inverted(true)
```

I found no such modifier

Next I tried using procedural variables, state variables, and custom binding variables, but they all gave the same error:

> Cannot use instance member 'settings' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: You can create your own toggle style

Comment: That might work. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this approach to have `...two toggles that both operate off the same variable, but the twist is that I want one to be the inverse of the variable and only be toggled on when the variable is false.`:

```
   Toggle(isOn: $myBooleanVar) {
    Text("Yes").frame(width: 80)
}

Toggle(isOn: Binding(
    get: { !myBooleanVar },
    set: { if !$0 { myBooleanVar = !$0 } } )) {  // <-- more logic if required
        Text("no").frame(width: 80)
    }
```

Comment: It works with only one small issue: Hitting the no button doesn't toggle the boolean. How do I fix this?

Comment: `... and only be toggled on when the variable is false`. If this is not what you want, then what is it?
For getting a `Toggle` as just the inverse of the other, use `set: { myBooleanVar = !$0 } ))`

Comment: Thanks, sorry if my phrasing was unclear.